# Vim: How to exclude already typed result from CTRL+N autocomplete

Tags: vim

I've searched the manual, but really have no idea what I'm looking for. Here's a screenshot of what happens when I'm typing a word and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to autocomplete it:

[image]

I obviously do not want to autocomplete the word I just typed as it's already typed, therefore don't need it to show in the results dropdown.

It doesn't show up every time I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, which is odd.

Comment: Use `<C-P>` instead? I think the original is there just incase you want to go back to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>  autocompletes with  words  starting
with the keyword at your  curson position, starting the search *forward*
(think of <kbd>N</kbd> as  "next). And in your case, you  do have a word
right on the same line that is  `requiredF`, which was found by the auto
complete.

If  your  desired  keyword  is  before your  cursor,  you  can  use  the
similar  command <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>  which  does the  search
*backwards*, thus  searching for the previous  possible completion. This
is the  most common command you  will use when you're  writing new text,
for example.

Comment: I didn't even consider the one on the same line. Thanks!